# trello API on custom fields using R

Tags: r, api, trello

I'm trying to update a custom field on trello.

I've gone ahead and created a dummy account to share it's credentials to make sure there is a reproducible example.

```
require("httr")
PUT("https://api.trello.com/1/cards/5f6888ab6301b68b8a614156/customField/5f6889e2d2536e5364eed893/item?key=d674c81261ea78489bcef67dda228790&token=bdcdd065a63b82fb0e2f5f98a7464791698e4fa98004ec02f2690bce9ce2a59d&value=")
content(GET("https://api.trello.com/1/boards/5f6888aa5f8b800c21e81f6e?key=d674c81261ea78489bcef67dda228790&token=bdcdd065a63b82fb0e2f5f98a7464791698e4fa98004ec02f2690bce9ce2a59d&cards=all&card_fields=all&customFields=true&card_customFieldItems=true"))[["cards"]][[1]][["customFieldItems"]][[1]][["value"]][["text"]]

PUT("https://api.trello.com/1/cards/5f6888ab6301b68b8a614156/customField/5f6889e2d2536e5364eed893/item?key=d674c81261ea78489bcef67dda228790&token=bdcdd065a63b82fb0e2f5f98a7464791698e4fa98004ec02f2690bce9ce2a59d&value=something")
content(GET("https://api.trello.com/1/boards/5f6888aa5f8b800c21e81f6e?key=d674c81261ea78489bcef67dda228790&token=bdcdd065a63b82fb0e2f5f98a7464791698e4fa98004ec02f2690bce9ce2a59d&cards=all&card_fields=all&customFields=true&card_customFieldItems=true"))[["cards"]][[1]][["customFieldItems"]][[1]][["value"]][["text"]]
```

line 2 I'm trying to delete the value on the field ("please change me from API")
line 3 I'm grabbing the value and realizing it's still the same

line 4 I'll try to change the value to "ee"
line 5 I'll check that it still isn't working.

the errors are slightly different (404 vs 400) so I'm guessing that I'm very close.

Comment: trello documentation: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-idcard-customfield-idcustomfield-item-put
I've been on this for days and grown several gray hairs because I don't know what trello expects from me when it says "Content type = application/json,
Value = oneOf [object, object]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took me several days but I finally got it.

For anyone who might have the same problem:
instead of using `"&value=something"` on the url itself you must use the body parameter from PUT. like this:

```
PUT("https://api.trello.com/1/cards/aa/customField/bb/item?key=cc&token=dd", body = list(value = list("text" = "something")), encode = "json")
```

it looks like the trello api needs the value to be passed in as json and that it has to be done though the body parameter.

Change `aa` `bb` `cc` `dd` and `something` according to what you want `"text"` also if using a different data type

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you can use the [API client](https://github.com/jchrom/trelloR):

```
library(trelloR)
update_card_field(card_id, field = "field_id", key = "text",
                  value = "Updated!")
```